# centos iptables, restrict tcp port to specific ips

Tags: centos, iptables, tcp, port

I would like to modify the iptables on my CentOS 5.8 server so that only specific ips can connect to the machine on a specific port.

Currently, I have the following in my iptables file:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
```

How would I modify that line if I wanted to allow access for only ips 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2 for instance? (they might not necessarily be sequential ips when I do this for reals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a match for each specific source IP with the `-s` flag, then forbid all others (if there's no later catchall rule to do that last bit for you):

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5000 -s 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5000 -s 1.1.1.2 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5000 -j REJECT
```

If the IPs that you wished to permit could be grouped by a subnet, you can simplify the rules slightly.  For example, if you wished to permit 1.1.1.2 and 1.1.1.3, you could use

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5000 -s 1.1.1.2/31 -j ACCEPT
```

again following it with a blanket `REJECT`, if needed.